# Expected type error from TS when using the :key attribute within v-for directive

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Attempting to [maintain state with a key](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key) for a `v-for` directive but typescript throws the following error on the `:key` attribute.

## TS Error

```
(property) key?: string | number | symbol
Type '{ toString: (radix?: number) => string; toFixed: (fractionDigits?: number) => string; toExponential: (fractionDigits?: number) => string; toPrecision: (precision?: number) => string; valueOf: () => number; toLocaleString: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.ts(2322)
runtime-dom.d.ts(1480, 3): The expected type comes from property 'key' which is declared here on type 'ElementAttrs<LiHTMLAttributes>'
```

## Code

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue';

  interface Workspace {
    id: Number
    name: String
  }

  const workspaceList = ref<Workspace[]>([])
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="workspace in workspaceList" :key="workspace.id">
        {{ workspace.id }}: {{ workspace.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you are not using the types that you intended in your `Workspace` interface members. You probably want primitives rather than their object counterparts (note the lowercase):

```ts
interface Workspace {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Reference the TS documentation for [everyday types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean):

> The type names `String`, `Number`, and `Boolean` (starting with capital letters) are legal, but refer to some special built-in types that will very rarely appear in your code. *Always* use `string`, `number`, or `boolean` for types.